# How to Convert dateTime from one timeZone to another in XSLT

Tags: xml, datetime, xpath, xslt-1.0, xalan

We are trying to convert DateTime from GMT to EST by using XSLT extensions. We are using java's SimpleDateFormat and TimeZone to set timeZone and format this. This is formating timeZone from one format to another but not converting DateTime to EST.
Can someone help me if I am missing something on this?

Here is my XSL for this-

```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:cal="java.util.GregorianCalendar" xmlns:tz="java.util.TimeZone" xmlns:dt="java.util.Date" xmlns:SimpleDateFormat="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl Extensions java math fn fo xs Extensions sf cal dt" xmlns:math="xalan://java.lang.Math" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java">
    
    
        <xsl:template name="convertGMTDateToEST">
                <xsl:variable name="dateString">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'08/17/20 17:58'" />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="inSDF" select="SimpleDateFormat:new('MM/dd/yy HH:mm')"/>
                <xsl:variable name="outSDF" select="SimpleDateFormat:new('MM-dd-yy HH:mm')"/>
                <xsl:variable name= "inTZ" select="tz:getTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata')"/>
                <xsl:variable name= "outTZ" select="tz:getTimeZone('America/New_York')"/>
                <xsl:variable name = "setTZToInput" select="SimpleDateFormat:setTimeZone($inSDF,$inTZ)"/>
                <xsl:variable name = "setTZToOutput" select="SimpleDateFormat:setTimeZone($outSDF,$outTZ)"/>
                <xsl:variable name = "inDate" select="SimpleDateFormat:parse($inSDF,$dateString)"/>
                <xsl:variable name= "outDate" select="SimpleDateFormat:format($outSDF,$inDate)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$outDate" /> 
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>
    
    
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current output - `08-17-20 17:58`
Expected output - `08-17-20 13:58`

**Note**- we are using  Xalan XSLT 1.0 engine - `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory`

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `TimeZone` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. I haven’t got experience with using Java inside XSLT, but I would suppose that it’s possible to use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to handle UTC to US/New york time, but in input timezone you pass time as IST

You should pass below

```
<xsl:variable name="inTZ" select="tz:getTimeZone('UTC')"/>
```

**Updated XSLT**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:cal="java.util.GregorianCalendar" xmlns:tz="java.util.TimeZone" xmlns:dt="java.util.Date" xmlns:SimpleDateFormat="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl java math fn fo xs cal dt" xmlns:math="xalan://java.lang.Math" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java">
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="convertGMTDateToEST"></xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="convertGMTDateToEST">
        <xsl:variable name="dateString">
            <xsl:value-of select="'08/17/20 17:58'" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="$dateString"/></xsl:message>
        <xsl:variable name="inSDF" select="SimpleDateFormat:new('MM/dd/yy HH:mm')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="outSDF" select="SimpleDateFormat:new('MM-dd-yy HH:mm')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="inTZ" select="tz:getTimeZone('UTC')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="outTZ" select="tz:getTimeZone('America/New_York')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="setTZToInput" select="SimpleDateFormat:setTimeZone($inSDF,$inTZ)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="setTZToOutput" select="SimpleDateFormat:setTimeZone($outSDF,$outTZ)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="inDate" select="SimpleDateFormat:parse($inSDF,$dateString)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="outDate" select="SimpleDateFormat:format($outSDF,$inDate)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$outDate" /> 
        
    </xsl:template>
    
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tried by changing IST to UTC but didn't work. Are we still missing something?